# understanding failure of chocolatey install of MSVC 2013 Express

Tags: visual-studio-2013, chocolatey

From an admin prompt, I'm trying to install MSVC 2013 Express (Desktop):

```
cinst VisualStudioExpress2013WindowsDesktop
```

but its failing.  Digging through the failure, I see that the installer returned exit code `3010`.  I'm not sure what this means, or why the Chocolatey script isn't handling it properly.

The full error output is in a gist [here](https://gist.github.com/paleozogt/3d97364e9f3831e4d8ae).

Comment: 3010 is actually a successful install that is waiting for a pending reboot. This should be one of the valid exit codes that is in the chocolateyInstall.ps1 script for that package, but the package author missed putting it in there.

Comment: We are getting smarter slowly about the different installer types, thus authors would not need to be so intimate about MSIEXEC and all of that fun.

Comment: @ferventcoder this seems to be the right answer as msvc seems to be functional after a reboot

Answer (score 0):

This is a standard error code that most Windows installation packages can issue (mode details can be found [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290158)).

Basically, this means that in order to install this package, you need to first reboot your machine.  This is the same error message that you would get if you were to run the MSI/EXE yourself.

I suspect that what you did was to first install Chocolatey, and then immediately start installing packages.  Due to the dependency of Chocolatey on the .Net Framework 4.0, immediately installing packages is not really advisable, as depending on the state of your machine, you are likely going to immediately need a reboot.

You should really install Chocolatey, reboot, and then start installing packages.

One thing that you have to remember is that Chocolatey is a Package Manager, it works with individual packages.  It doesn't understand, and nor should it, the interaction of multiple packages.  As a result, it doesn't know about the requirements of reboots, it simply installs the package.

There are other tools, like [Boxstarter](http://boxstarter.org/), that provide functionality to detect whether a reboot is required, and this handles that requirement.

Comment: I started from scratch in a Win7 VM, installed all the updates, rebooted, installed chocolatey, rebooted, then installed `VisualStudioExpress2013WindowsDesktop` and still got the `3010` error.

Comment: I think @ferventcoder has the right answer in his/her comments. The install seems to function properly if I ignore the `3010` error.

Comment: That makes sense.  Glad you got it sorted!

Comment: I have sent the maintainer of the package an email suggesting that they add the 3010 as a valid exit code for the application.